# Dagger, multi module projects & incremental builds performance

Tags: android, dagger-2

Does it make sense to create an independent `@Component` in each module, and couple components using `dependencies=[FeatureDepsProvider::class]` instead of using `Subcomponents` to save build time on incremental builds?

For example, if I use subcomponents in gradle feature modules, and change something in subcomponent's graph that requires to regenerate it, it will also regenerate parent component, because it's a subclass, right?

What will happen if I use components? If I change something in feature component, but don't change public interface of this component, will other components which depend on this public interface be regenerated too?

Example:

```html
interface DependencyProvider {
 fun provideDep(): SomeDependency
}

// first gradle module
@Component
interface FeatureComponent : DependencyProvider {}

// second gradle module
@Component(dependencies = [DependencyProvider::class])
interface ConsumerComponent {
}
```

Also, I'd like to have some explanation on how incremental annotation processor works for Dagger

Comment: please take the extra 2 seconds to write out `something` instead of `smth`. not everyone has english as a first language, we have to make posts understandable to everyone :)